# Cannot resolve some classes of jdk 8 in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am using jdk1.8.0_31. But i cannot implement class in my project [YearMonth](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) which introduced in jdk 1.8. My concept on jdk is not clear. Is there any relationship between jdk version vs api version (Compatibility issues) ? Is the all features are inherited in android after release of latest jdk ?

Comment: Android does not use the latest version of Java. There is a large delay between when a version of Java is released, and when Android officially supports it.

Comment: [`JSR-310`](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-new-date-and-time) is new date time API introduced in Java 8. Android does not ship with Java 8. [JodaTime](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) is the recommended library for handling time on Android.

Comment: There is a JSR-310 backport for [Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), and [Java 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) in general.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to File/project structure in android studio and for source compatibility select 1.8 you can't because android studio doesn't. This [lawsuit](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2970944/android/oracle-google-has-destroyed-the-market-for-java.html) explains why google is not so eager to support java for now. As for time/year/month/dates etc. Java 8 has [instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/instant.html) for recording times and dates ...

Answer (score 1):

Check your android API and see what java versions are supported. Most of the time when an api is designed a lot of efforts put in place to support lower JDK(specially > JDK 1.5) versions but the people don't have control on latest Java versions.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum SDK level defines what you can use or not. Java 8 is currently not supported by Android. Please refer the below post for more details

[Which JDK version (Language Level) is required for Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869069/which-jdk-version-language-level-is-required-for-android-studio)

[API level with JRE versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281924/api-level-with-jre-versions)