# Android Calendar Serialization Incompatible with Java 6

Tags: java, android, sockets, serialization, calendar

I am attempting to use an object serialization socket connection between a Java server and an Android client . I have run into problems when trying to send a Calendar object over this connection.

The Calendar object is sent by the Java server and received by the Android client, but I get the error message in LogCat:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: expected receiver of type java.util.TimeZone, but got null

I realize that it is not deserializing properly.

I prepared this code sample to reproduce the error:

Java Server:

```
public class SerializeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(49100);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        OutputStream oStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream ooStream = new ObjectOutputStream(oStream);

        String testString = "This is a test String";
        Calendar testCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        ooStream.writeObject(testCalendar);
        ooStream.reset();
        ooStream.close();

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Android Client:
(I created a blank project and added Internet permission to the manifest)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 49100);
                    InputStream iStream = socket.getInputStream();
                    ObjectInputStream oiStream = new ObjectInputStream(iStream);

                    Object object = oiStream.readObject();
                    Log.d("Test", object.toString());
                    oiStream.close();

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

}
```

Using that code sample, if you start the Java Server, then run the Android Client in the android emulator, you should receive the error.

I noticed that the java.util.Calendar object in the android-17/android.jar is different from the java.util.Calendar object in jre6. However they both share the same serialVersionUID of 1807547505821590642L. (Which tells me they were meant to be compatible through serialization).

So I guess I am looking for an explanation of what is going on here, and I am wondering, can I use one of the calendar objects on both Java and Android? (If so, how?) Is there a different object that I should be using instead?

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you find the solution?

Comment: I ended up using JSON instead of Object serialization. I used gson (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to help abstract it enough that it was as easy and transparent as using object serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am attempting to use an object serialization socket connection between a Java server and an Android client

That is unlikely to work well.

> I realize that it is not deserializing properly.

That is a fine example of why it is unlikely to work well. Android is committed to maintaining binary API compatibility. The internal implementation of any class is subject to modification, meaning that the Java-style object serialization is subject to modification.

> can I use one of the calendar objects on both Java and Android?

Sure. Just do not use Java-style object serialization between disparate platforms.

Either pass the value as a `long` (`getTimeInMillis()`), or write your own JSON/XML/protobuf/whatever serializer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one to one mapping between a JavaSE version and an Android version. Android and Java are evolving differently. See these SO questions:

- [How does Android's Java version relate to a Java SE version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535385/how-does-androids-java-version-relate-to-a-java-se-version)
- [JRE on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390482/jre-on-android)

Because of this, I think the guys that worked on Android didn't even bothered to change the `serialVersionUID` of the common classes. Serialization compatibility is one of the most sensible issues when evolving classes from one JDK version to another, imagine the headache to maintain serialization compatibility between JavaSE and Android.