# Is it possible to develop an Android application with C#?

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Google Android ever support .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214615/will-google-android-ever-support-net)
>   [Is there a way to develop C#/.NET on Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443690/is-there-a-way-to-develop-c-net-on-android-devices)

I don't have an experience with mobile applications and as a .Net developer I would like to ask if it is possible to develop Android applications with C#?

If yes, does this mean I can use Visual Studio for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a commercial framework called [MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) created for this purpose. It appears to support Visual Studio 2010.

The iOS alternative, [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch), is restricted to Mac usage I believe.

To be honest, it looks like it has recently been farmed off to another supplier and the prices have jumped... I'd be hesitant before buying in and I'd likely try and learn Java/Objective-C instead - unless I knew I was going to make squillions!

Comment: I would like to make a squillion dollars!  How many zeroes in a squillion?