# Running .NET Program on Android

Tags: c#, android, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Develop Android app using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962104/develop-android-app-using-c-sharp)

I have a program written in C# with .NET Framework. I want to run this on Android. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [Mono for Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Mono for Android at http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid.

While your code may require some changes (especially if it calls Windows-specific methods), this should make it easy to port your program to an Android environment.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK is Java and no C#. Unless you can publish your C# as website or webapplication (browser accessable) you cannot do this without help.

You could try Mono for Android and edit your code if required.

http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid