# Is it possible to write apps for Android in C#?

Tags: c#, android, compiler-construction

We all know that Android runs Dalvik VM programs.

Normally developers write programs in Java and they compile it to Dalvik bytecode.

I wonder if it would be possible to create a compiler that can take C# code and compile it into Dalvik bytecode.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214615/will-google-android-ever-support-net  And why the community wiki?

Comment: And so it is a duplicate... nevermind then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, that's one option - or you could just run it on Mono running on Android. This has [already been done](http://www.koushikdutta.com/2009/01/mono-on-android-with-gratuitous-shaky.html) and [the Mono team is now working on MonoDroid](http://www.upvery.com/10130-monodroid-will-be-available-from-august.html). I'm not sure of details yet - whether that will be running the Dalvik VM as well for UI, whether it will just be native, or whether it will be a .NET-to-Dalvik compiler.