# Platform for develop on multi OS-Phone

Tags: iphone, android

I want develop on Android and iPhone...

How Platform can i use?

Comment: related / possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821085/technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 3):

[Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/) and [Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) both provide platforms where you can develop for both Android and iPhone in the same application without using different languages, just using one JavaScript API.

Native iPhone apps are written in Objective-C and Android's in Java. You can use either of the JS alternatives mentioned earlier, on any platform: unix, or microsoft. 
Should you want to build a native iPhone app, people tend to use xcode on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

An intel based Mac,

- You need a mac to develop iPone apps, no other choice unless you want to target jail broken phones
- The Mac is also supported development
  environment for android

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you mean by platform.  You will need at least a Mac Mini (Intel Mac) to develop for the iPhone if you're asking about hardware requirements.

Mono/C# + MonoDevelop fits the bill software wise for writing the code once and (with tweaks) getting it to work on multiple platforms.  See this related [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074452/programming-games-for-iphone/3074476#3074476).

Comment: I'm presuming this got a downvote due to C# not being the native language for either android or iphone, its confusing as it implies that you'd need to install Mono, which is notoriously slow on a mac, which is not necessary for this iphone/android dev as objective-c compiler ships with xcode, and java is built in on osx.

Comment: I have no idea why this got a downvote besides animosity towards either C# or Mono, but neither objective-c nor java are appropriate answers to the question as neither would work on BOTH mobile platforms.  If "platform" means dev machine then an Intel Mac is the only choice but if "platform" means source code language or dev environment then C# + MonoDevelop is a more appropriate answer until someone gets java running on the iPhone or objective-c running on Android.