# Mobile applications built with .NET?

Tags: .net, mobile

Can we develop mobile applications using .NET? Which mobiles are supported? Are those applications supported on all mobiles, or any particular mobiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider writing a web application that exposes views/pages specifically designed for mobile clients.

You could write your application in ASP.NET webforms or MVC, and programatically detect which page/view to best serve to that client.

For some idea on how to make that application look, see [Scott Hanselman's 2008 post on the Best Mobile Websites](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/bestmobilewebsitesfortinybrowsers.aspx).

Recommended as well to listen to [Scott's podcast on ASP.NET and the Mobile Web](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast154ASPNETAndTheMobileWeb.aspx). They focus their discussion on the [Mobile Device Browser File](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/) - definitions for individual mobile devices and browsers. At run time, ASP.NET uses the information in the request header to determine what type of device/browser has made the request.

**Native apps**

Currently, [Windows Phone 7 can be developed](http://developer.windowsphone.com/) with Silverlight/XAML with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [.NET compact framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497273.aspx).  This will allow development of applications on a version of the .NET framework specialized for running on systems with limited resources.  Microsoft is also touting the new [Windows 7 phone](http://developer.windowsphone.com/)

You can also write for .NET using Mono on the Android operating system according to [Will Google Android ever support .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214615/will-google-android-ever-support-net)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of families of phones that support development using .NET.

#### iOS

You can develop for iOS using [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/). This allows you to crate apps using C# code that looks and smells like usual C# code. Under the covers the code get compiled into chunks of native code, rather into CLR.

#### Windows Mobile phones

There is a port of `Windows.Forms` for Windows Mobile. The interface is similar to desktop WinForms.

#### Windows Phone 7

WinPhone7 deevlopment is 100% managed C# code using either Silverlight(WPF) or XNA Studio(gaming).