# Dot net application for Android mobiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Google Android ever support .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214615/will-google-android-ever-support-net)

Hi,
  I have googled lot for getting how to create dot net application for Android mobile phones (such as LG Optimus GT540), but not found relative information. My question is, is it possible to create dot net applications for Android mobiles or not? If yes, can anybody explain me the proper way to create such application and to deploy it onto the mobile phone.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214615/will-google-android-ever-support-net

Answer (score 5):

Novell is working on MonoDroid (http://monodroid.net/), which will enable C# development for Android the same way MonoTouch does it for iOS.

Comment: I didn't know about this, but if it's priced similar to Monotouch, a single dev license will probably eventually cost around 3-4 hundred.

Comment: Yes, it will most probably be priced like MonoTouch. At least they explicitly stated it is going to be commercially licensed.

Answer (score 2):

I guess if you can find a compiler that turns C# into Dalvik bytecode.

On thing to remember here is that ".NET" is a framework, the functionality it offers probably isn't going to be available in Dalvik (I could be wrong).  You might get core .NET APIs eventually, but I don't ever see "dynamic" and "expando" showing up.  However, there are alternatives that let you use .NET languages to target the DVM, think Mono:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=465590