# develop own android application on .net - what free framework?

Tags: android, .net

Is there free framework for develop andoroid application using .net (c# / VB) ? I find Novell distribution but free version support only emulator testing, but I want to check on my HTC Wildfire.

Any experience with create android app using .net languages?

Comment: there are no coloboration with google and microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there free framework for develop andoroid application using .net (c# / VB) ?

No. MonoDroid exists but is not free.

Answer (score 1):

[Will Google Android ever support .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214615/will-google-android-ever-support-net)

there is a trial version of Mono for Android;

http://android.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Basic4Android](http://www.basic4ppc.com/), this is very nice IDE for visual basic developer.

I hope it will help you. Go and develop android apps using microsoft technology.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product, by chance?