# Use C# mono for android or java?

Tags: c#, java, android, mono, platform

As a c# developer from a java background should you refresh your java skills or wait for the mono platform to be patched officially onto android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will Google Android ever support .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214615/will-google-android-ever-support-net)

Comment: there is no reasons for using mono ... you still have to learn "thinking in android" ... so, i think, you can learn both in the same time(java and "android")

Comment: What do you mean by "patched officially"? Mono for Android is available, but not free.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - MonoDroid is not "Mono for Android" its more or less a C#->Android Platform Java wrapper class.  One could write their own if they wanted.

Comment: @Ramhound monodroids official name is currently "Mono for Android". And it's far more than a wrapper class. It contains stuff like a co-operative GC and of course developer tools.

Answer (score 5):

Check the [MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) project. Android native apps can be created using C# and .NET framework. The disadvantage is the price, it is not free.

Comment: +1. if you want to write .NET on Android monodroid is your best bet. Having said that it is just .NEt with a custom UI framework on top. You don't get WPF, Silverlight or WindowsForms support.

Answer (score 2):

I learned C# on my own and now Java in my Job and did a test on mono for android, but it was rather easy to write my simple apps in native java than getting started in mono for android, but this might just be my opinion